# Error when use "java -jar corda.jar --initial-registration --network-root-truststore-password" for Corda Testnet

Tags: corda

Following this article https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html#installing-the-certificates-on-the-nodes

I try to use "java -jar corda.jar --initial-registration --network-root-truststore-password" for register with Corda Testnet and I got error from command prompt

[error from command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFLvI.png)

This is a little detail in node.conf

```
compatibilityZoneURL="https://map.testnet.corda.network"
devMode=true
```

I already follow https://testnet.corda.network/platform and start with cloud platform and it's work but I need to change "myLegalname" and initial register on my own.

so I want to know are.

1. Is Corda Testnet support java -jar corda.jar --initial-registration --network-root-truststore-password
2. If Support why this error happen
3. If Not so what doorman I should use

Many thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from R3 guy. It's because of Corda Testnet doesn't support initial registration for now.